# Cannot use Get-ChildItem to list filesnames in powershell script

Tags: powershell, directory

In the powershell command-line I can execute the following

```
$list = Get-ChildItem $path -name
foreach($k in $list){Write-host $k}
```

And it will list all the filenames in $path

But if I copy and paste the same thing in code to execute, the output is blank

Why would this even happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Write-Host` will write the string directly to the `Host` aka. the command line window, nowhere else

Just replace `Write-Host` with `Write-Output` if you want $k written to `STDOUT`:

```
$list = Get-ChildItem $path -name
foreach($k in $list){Write-Output $k}
```

But in reality, that is unnecessary, `Write-Output` is called implicitly. You could achieve the same thing with just:

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Name
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted just a list of files sorted by size without directory headers.  I used this to accomplish it.

get-childitem foldername -file -recurse | select FullName,Length | sort Length -descending | export-csv c:\export.csv